# Anatomically Correct Shrek

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design, evolution, fantasy-races

This is a shrekmission for the [Anatomically Correct Shrekis](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series/2798#2798)

you know him, you love him, you probably warship him it's [Shrek](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CaUR7h4WunY&has_verified=1) (more specifically the ogres from [Shrok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrek))!

[image]

Based on all the available data we know these ogrelords:

- Can range in height from 7ft (213.3cm) to 8ft (243.8cm) tall
- are as or stronger than a gorilla
- have hippo like ears
- reside in swamps
- are green in coloration
- have at least mildly toxic farts
- can use their ears to play music

Given these characteristics, what species could these Ogres have evolved from, and what evolutionary pressures would lead to these gods among men?

> Note: Bonus point if they
>
> - are like onions in some way
> - interact with donkeys
> - have ultrasonic roars
> - can dance

note II: this is more of a joke post than anything

Comment: Do you realize how absurd is to ask for a roar (which is sound) to be supersonic?

Comment: In february you asked questions about orcs where your premise was in few points similar to this. Please change the question or I will vote to close it as duplicate.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY why yes this and my orc question have some basic similarity i believe that there enough difference to warrant it's existence

Comment: I think all of this is trivial, at least at the start. Are you seriously building a world? Where are you stuck? Maybe there is another question at the core here about evolution and how to make it work in fiction

Comment: @Raditz_35 i was intending to make this sort of a joke post which is why i wait for April first.

Comment: supersonic is an adjective I think you mean ultrasonic :D

Comment: @user6760 well that's a serious blunder

Comment: Oh I see. Well, I actually didn't see that because somehow your joke post is just like most other posts here. I guess it's a parody then which I appreciate

Comment: Do Users gain Points by merely *asking a question *? - asking for a friend

Comment: @Joe you have to get your question voted on for points

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Shrek is a commercial third party intellectual property. WB.SE isn't for satisfying idle curiosity about other people's work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While this may be a joke question, I'm going to take a serious crack at it.

First, start with human or a proto-human.  We need intelligence (not listed), and that's the easiest way to get it.

> - Can range in height from 7ft (213.3cm) to 8ft (243.8cm) tall

Normal size variation between species.

> - are as or stronger than a gorilla

More normal variation.  Might also use some of the alternate muscular attachment found in some apes.

> - have hippo like ears
> - reside in swamps
> - can use their ears to play music

These three together.  They started living in swamps for defensive purposes.  (Much as humans took to water.)  In order to (almost) completely submerge for long periods, their eustachian tubes became functional as an nasal extension, and the middle and outer ear connected.  They can thus inhale and exhale through their ears.  The ear shape then modified so it can extend upward to the water surface.  The "music" is simply a result of this breathing, when pushed enough to get a "turbulent" flow.

> - are green in coloration

This could be either a normal pigmentation variation (perhaps for camouflage) or an algae colony on or under the skin.

> - have at least mildly toxic farts

I think humans already qualify for this.  But for shrek, we probably should just add some more interesting intestinal flora, perhaps combined with something interesting in the diet.

> - are like onions in some way

This was "have layers".  If the green is algae, they could literally molt from time to time.

> - interact with donkeys

talking donkeys: as a non-hostile intelligence, it is something one can befriend -- or not.

animal donkeys: some wandered into the swamps and were domesticated by the shreks.

> - have ultrasonic roars

Probably related to the ear/nose modifications.

> - can dance

Intelligence, poise, and some training.